# Django form: select field after the submit of the form

Tags: python, django, forms, select

I have a report form report.html:

```
<select id="select" class="form-control" name="organization">
        <option value="">-- Select Organization --</option>
        {% for organization in organization_list %}
        <option value="{{ organization.name }}">{{ organization.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

After the submitting this form the selected organization is not saved. But it would be better if the organization will be displayed. It can be helpful for the user: she/he can see, what filter displays these results.

How to save and show after form submitting the selected value for the select field?

views.py:

```
def report(request):

    user = request.user
    admin = None
    try:
        admin = user.administrator
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    if not admin:
        return render(request, 'vms/no_admin_rights.html')

    organization_list = get_organizations_ordered_by_name()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            organization = form.cleaned_data['organization']
            event_name = form.cleaned_data['event_name']
            job_name = form.cleaned_data['job_name']
            start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            report_list = get_administrator_report(
                first_name,
                last_name,
                organization,
                event_name,
                job_name,
                start_date,
                end_date
                )
            total_hours = calculate_total_report_hours(report_list)
            return render(request, 'administrator/report.html', {'form': form, 'report_list': report_list, 'total_hours': total_hours, 'notification': True, 'organization_list': organization_list})
        else:
            return render(request, 'administrator/report.html', {'form': form, 'notification': False, 'organization_list': organization_list})
    else:
        form = ReportForm()
        return render(request, 'administrator/report.html', {'form': form, 'notification': False, 'organization_list': organization_list})
```

forms.py:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[(A-Z)|(a-z)|(\s)]+$', max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[(A-Z)|(a-z)|(\s)]+$', max_length=30, required=False)
    organization = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[(A-Z)|(a-z)|(\s)]+$', max_length=75, required=False)
    event_name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[(A-Z)|(a-z)|(0-9)|(\s)|(\.)|(,)|(\-)|(!)]+$', max_length=75, required=False)
    job_name = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[(A-Z)|(a-z)|(\s)]+$', max_length=75, required=False)
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return render(request, 'administrator/report.html', {'form': form, 'report_list': report_list, 'total_hours': total_hours, 'notification': True, 'organization_list': organization_list})
```

add to the context `'selected_organization': organization`:

```
return render(request, 'administrator/report.html', {'form': form, 'report_list': report_list, 'total_hours': total_hours, 'notification': True, 'organization_list': organization_list, 'selected_organization': organization})
```

And report form should look like this:

```
<select id="select" class="form-control" name="organization">
    <option value="">-- Select Organization --</option>
    {% for organization in organization_list %}
    <option value="{{ organization.name }}" {% if selected_organization == organization %}selected{% endif %}>{{ organization.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped